# Loop assignment doubt

Tags: matlab

What does `result` mean inside a while loop in Matlab

```
while (some_condition == 1)

   A = somefunc();
   result(iteration) = A;
   iteration = iteration + 1; 
   ...

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable option seems to be that `result` is a variable (array or matrix) defined outside of your while loop and you assign the value `A` to index `iteration` of `result`.

**[Edit]** The second option is: `result` is function taking as argument `iteration`. While this is in theory possible, it makes no sense, since  assigning a value to the result of a function in MATLAB will create a variable with that function's name and as a result *hide* that function in the scope of the variable.

E.g. try:

```
a = randi(10, 10, 2);
sum(a) = 5
b = 6;
sum(b)
```

As you will see, `sum(b)` does not return 6 (= b). It now returns the 6th element of the array `sum`, which was set to 5 in the 2nd line of code. Access to the function just became impossible.